# How to insert alt tag into php image

Tags: tags, alt

I would like to insert an alt tag into this php code

```
<?php $image_url='https://www.whatever.com/book2.png'; ?>
```

but if i try and do it the page goes blank and i guess i need that $image_url part instead of using a href

please help i have tried to do

```
<?php echo img(array('src'=>'www.whatever.com/book2.png', 'alt'=> 'alt information')); ?>
```

but it doesnt work for my page i guess it's missing the $image_url part

Comment: That is just the image path. Can you paste the code for the img tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you havent provided much to go on I am taking a shot in the dark. You can try something like this:

```
<img src="<?php $image_url='https://www.whatever.com/book2.png'; ?>" alt="" />
```

Your alt tag will go in the img tag. Dont forget the width and height of the image or it will display at its original resolution.

Hope this is what you were after.

Cheers

Comment: It didn't work what im trying to do is add an alt to the image so it can be verified on my seo score:(

Comment: Can you  update your post with more code? What you have given is just a PHP variable with an image path. The path needs an image source to display an image as well as alt tag.